# Apllying Generalized Stokes Theorem

Tags: analysis, manifolds, stokes-theorem, orientation

I'm having no difficulties to understand the theorical concepts about the Generalized Stokes Theorem, but I'm having trouble to applying it.

Let $M$ the semiellipsoid in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ defined by $4x^{2}+y^{2}+4z^{2}=4$ and $y\geq 0$. Show that M is, in fact, an oriented 2-manifold and describe the boundary of $M$. Well, to describe $\partial M$ is easy.

How can I find the induced orientation for $\partial M$ by the orientation of $M$? Actually, is there any method to find a orientation?

If I know that I can verify the Stokes Theorem, but I'm not getting.

Comment: Why is this any more difficult than it would be for a hemisphere in $\Bbb R^3$? It's identical. Just learn the definition and do it.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm starting my studies into Stokes Theorem, that's my first prattical exercise. Even if you show me the obvious, will help

Comment: Think about the normal vector to $M$.